# DB2 database name is case sensitive or not

Tags: database, jdbc, db2

In my DB2, I created database with name 'SAMPLE'. And, while connect with Razor DB2 client, it can connect to 'SAMPLE' database without case-sensitive.

For example,

> jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/sAmple
>
> jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/Sample
>
> jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/saMple
>
> jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/SAMPLE

They all can connect to DB2. But when I take results with them, only SAMPLE database can show results. I want to know that how I can connect to DB2 with only 'SAMPLE' database name with case-sensitive.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "when I take results with them, only SAMPLE database can show results"?

Comment: "select * from TABLE(SNAP_GET_BP(CAST(NULL as varchar(255)), -1)) where db_name='SAMPLE'" can show results.

Comment: Instead "select * from TABLE(SNAP_GET_BP(CAST(NULL as varchar(255)), -1)) where db_name='sample'" can not show results. But It can connect successfully to SAMPLE database.

Comment: Either transform the parameter for db_name before handing it over to the sql, or use `upper` or `ucase` function as in `where db_name=upper('sample')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DB2 databases are not case sensitive `SAMPlE = sample = SAMple`. However:

- Some tools need the upper case in order to work. Probably, they take into account the instance directory (`db2 list db directory`)
- The database name is changed to upper case for internal identification and it is stored like this in the database catalog. And any function that use the database name should be in upper case.

This behavior is similar to a table. For example, `EMPLOYEE = employee`, but the table is stored as `EMPLOYEE` in the database catalog. However, you can force the name in lower case by surrounding by quotes, like `"employee"`, but this is considered as a bad practice. In the other hand, database name does not keep the case is surrounded by quotes.